# Eventbridge rule causing ACL setting on S3 file to fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, acl, aws-event-bridge

I have a lambda function which writes a file to S3, and an EventBridge rule triggering another lambda to process the file.

The first lambda uses `upload_file` with `ExtraArgs` to write metadata, ContentType and ACL like so (Python code):

```py
extra_args = {
    'Metadata': metadata, # dict[str, str]
    'ContentType': 'video/mp4',
    'ACL': 'public-read',
}

response = s3_client.upload_file(
    Filename=file,
    Bucket=bucket,
    Key=key,
    ExtraArgs=extra_args,
)
```

The first time I tried adding the ACL bit, it failed with a permissions error because I hadn't included `s3:PutAcl` in the role. Once I added it, the upload worked fine, the metadata had been set, but the ACL and ContentType hadn't been.

Testing this locally, everything worked fine. I even tried assuming the role the lambda had, and it worked fine.

I managed to get it to work by changing the folder the file was uploaded to. This led me to believe that the EventBridge rule on the prefix (that folder name) was somehow responsible for it breaking.

I changed the prefix on the EventBridge rule to something else, and this fixed it. But of course I need the EventBridge rule for my workflow, so I need a way of reinstating the rule without breaking the ACL/ContentType setting.

The S3 bucket infra:

```yaml
  ClipsBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref ClipsBucketName
      NotificationConfiguration:
        EventBridgeConfiguration:
          EventBridgeEnabled: true
```

The execution role:

```yaml
LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      [...]
      Policies:
        [...]
        - PolicyName: allowS3
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:PutObject
                  - s3:PutObjectAcl
                Resource:
                  - !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${ClipsBucketName}/*
```

The EventBridge rule:

```json
{
  "detail-type": ["Object Created"],
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail": {
    "bucket": {
      "name": ["bucket-name"]
    },
    "object": {
      "key": [{
        "prefix": "auto/"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried:

- Various alternatives to `s3_client.upload_file` such as using the s3 resource method, `put_object`, etc
- Uploading the file without ACL, then setting the ACL separately afterwards
- Changing the EventBridge rule detail to `Object ACL Updated`

By "running locally", I mean executing `python lambda_function.py` (optionally with `--profile xxx` where `xxx` is the name of the profile with the lambda's role ARN)

I don't understand how the EventBridge rule could be preventing the ACL/ContentType being set without causing an error - I got an error when it didn't have permission to write ACL. I don't understand why it works locally (even when writing to the folder with the EventBridge rule set on it). I also don't know of a good way of debugging this.

Comment: Are you able to share a few more items like: the policy (or the relevant statement in the policy) that you believe is permitting this action), the command you ran locally to test (guessing awscli or similar) and what permissions that was done with (possibly "admin" if it's your user account)

Answer (score 0):

**I'd file this under "the question is wrong".**

It turns out the second lambda was copying the file onto itself (as a workaround for not being able to easily add a piece of metadata), which meant the ContentType and ACL were not being preserved.

It hadn't occurred to me that the problem could be occurring *after* the eventbridge trigger. I assumed that me looking at the file immediately, seeing it not have ContentType and ACL set, that the setting of those properties was not getting done in the first place, when in actuality it was - but immediately being overwritten by the second lambda.